# Truffle solidity tests are executed before end of deployment

Tags: truffle, testing, truffle-migration

My contract hierarchy is `Token` which calls function on `TokenBase`. The deployment is defined like so:

```
var Token = artifacts.require("./Token.sol");
var TokenBase = artifacts.require("./TokenBase.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  //deployer.deploy(Accounts);
  deployer.deploy(Token, "SweetCoin", "SWC")
  .then(function() {
    console.log("deployment log Token address is", Token.address);
    deployer.deploy(TokenBase, Token.address, 0, 0, 1000).then(function() {
        console.log("deployment log TokenBase address is", TokenBase.address);
    });
  })
};
```

this seems to work fine as the output of `truffle migrate` is

```
deployment log Token address is 0xf10382227656670bc71d5433ae51e6826fabfff1
deployment log TokenBase address is 0xf0d762e793e1691cc2f80787e74ce3715479652e
```

when `truffle test` is run it looks like `TokenBase` is instantiated after the start of the test contract. This is the output after `truffle test`

```
deployment log Token address is 0x87a224644edcac90885cc6ca8099dc989d89ed36


TestToken
deployment log TokenBase address is 0xfefe73e3abd10d82461161298e0db6f1b1225da7
    1) testSetUp
    > No events were emitted


0 passing (446ms)
1 failing

1) TestToken testSetUp:
    Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/Users/mroon/.nvm/versions/node/v7.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:35:16)
    at /Users/mroon/.nvm/versions/node/v7.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:36
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/Users/mroon/.nvm/versions/node/v7.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:118:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/Users/mroon/.nvm/versions/node/v7.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/Users/mroon/.nvm/versions/node/v7.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/Users/mroon/.nvm/versions/node/v7.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/mroon/.nvm/versions/node/v7.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:24)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
```

And finally this is the test contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.10;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";

import "../contracts/Token.sol";
import "../contracts/TokenBase.sol";

contract TestToken {
    Token token;
    TokenBase tokenBase;

    function testSetUp() {
        token = Token(DeployedAddresses.Token());
        tokenBase = TokenBase(DeployedAddresses.TokenBase());
    }

}
```

The reason I suspect a sync issue is that if I remove the second line in the test: `tokenBase = TokenBase(DeployedAddresses.TokenBase());` the test passes.

The question obviously is: how can I make my test pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are not returning a promise from within deployer().deploy().then

Add `return` before `deployer.deploy(TokenBase, Token.address, 0, 0, 1000).then`

I'd write the whole thing like this:

```
  deployer.deploy(Token, "SweetCoin", "SWC").then(function() {
    console.log("deployment log Token address is", Token.address);
    return Token.address;
  }).then(function(){
    return deployer.deploy(TokenBase, Token.address, 0, 0, 1000)
  }).then(function(){
    console.log("TokenBase deployed at: ", TokenBase.address);
  });
```